# Cannot source a directory: "/home/myname/.config/nvim/init.vim"

Tags: neovim

What does the error in the title mean and how do I fix it?
I am following a tutorial online to install some plugins for Neovim, but I just noticed this error.
That directory does exist, and when I open the init.vim file there is stuff in there that I didn't add.

This is what is in the init.vim file when I open it with nvim:

```
" ==============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v165)
"   /home/myname/.config/nvim/init.vim
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
```

Comment: You have accidentally created a *directory*, AKA *folder* called init.vim, instead of a *file*. It doesn't contain the text "Netrw Directory Listing", that is the name of the plug-in that lets you view directories. You probably want to delete the directory, and start again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
source $HOME /.config/nvim/init.vim
```

or you can split your settings using folders.

plug-in, module, theme etc. Just create a path and file and give address like below:

```
source $HOME /.config/nvim/theme/theme.vim
```